# Explicitly enable SBT plugin inside another SBT plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing a sbt plugin to abstract away some boilerplate involved with a few common plugins that I use. In this quest, [one of the plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo)'s I'm trying to configure has it's `requires` set to `noTrigger` which requires explicitly enabling the plugin in the project setting.

With SBT AutoPlugin's if I set `requires = BuildInfoPlugin` and `trigger = allRequirements` then the settings will auto load if I explicitly enable the base plugin, or if I set requires as above and `trigger = noTrigger` then explicitly adding the plugin I'm working on will import the base plugin as well.

```
/* Requires enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin) to be explicitly set on project,
   then the settings in this plugin will automatically load. */
object BuildInformation extends AutoPlugin {

  override def requires = BuildInfoPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
}
```

.

```
/* Requires enablePlugins(BuildInformation) to be explicitly set on project,
   which will automatically import BuildInfoPlugin */
object BuildInformation extends AutoPlugin {

  override def requires = BuildInfoPlugin
}
```

Is there any way to have the derivative plugin explicitly import the base plugin, without requiring the derivative plugin itself to be explicitly added? (E.g. PlayScala plugin from PlayFramework pulls in sbt-native-packager with it's load, but PlayScala is required to be explicitly enabled)

One thing I was thinking of is just extending the base plugin, and overriding it's triggers method to be `allRequirements`, but was wondering if there is a cleaner / more preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Not more elegant than deriving, but maybe more flexible:

```
object DerivedPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override def trigger: PluginTrigger = allRequirements
  override def requires = JvmPlugin

  val autoImport = BasePlugin.autoImport

  override lazy val projectSettings = BasePlugin.projectSettings

}
```